# Hit Ctrl+c during do-release-upgrade. Did I break it?

Tags: upgrade

I did a do-release-upgrade. During the process I was asked if I wanted to replace my rsync config file in init.d with the new version or keep the existing one. I hit D to look at the diff and then could not get back to the question / install script. I stupidly hit ctrl c and was not returned to the upgrade process but to the shell.

I am now worried I have a broken install :( What should I do?

Comment: You can run again, do-release-upgrade to restart the release upgrade.

Comment: The answers here did not work for me. I found another one here http://serverfault.com/questions/387547/how-do-i-reattach-to-ubuntu-servers-do-release-upgrade-process that worked much better.

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock && sudo dpkg --configure -a` (close to what I found in serverfault.com/a/323422/51150 )

Comment: I just had to press Enter again to continue after `Inhibiting until Ctrl+C` happened. Use system monitor to check if it's actually downloading, you should see a line for hundreds of packages downloading if it's actually working.

Comment: I ended up [killing a still-running `dpkg`](https://serverfault.com/a/454415/266986) and finishing the configuration steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649364/i-hit-control-c-in-a-do-release-upgrade-subprocess-how-do-i-recover).

Answer (score 12):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` was most probably changed to the new version at the point you aborted the upgrade. This will make `do-release-upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` behavior unpredictable.

- Change it first with (assuming you were upgrading from 11.10):

  `sudo sed -i -e 's/precise/oneiric/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Then do a `sudo apt-get update` followed by a `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: You may also need to rollback `/etc/lsb_release`

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way than replacing the dist name in source.list with sed as mentioned in another answer. The upgrader creates a /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade backup file, you just have to rename it to /etc/apt/sources.list to restore your original sources.list, `apt update` and then restart do-release-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can run again `do-release-upgrade` to restart the release upgrade.

The release upgrade, will start from the beginning, again.

Comment: Depending on how far you made it through the upgrade process, this may not work, and you'll have to edit sources.list

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to **continue the release upgrade** after an accidental CTRL + C **without killing the dpkg process** or **restarting the release upgrade again**.

**Disclaimer**: this solution won't work if you killed the screen session too. In that case [killing the dpkg process](https://serverfault.com/a/454415/266986) is the way to go.

All you have to know about the do-release-upgrade

1. it is running inside screen
2. the process starts an additional ssh daemon at port '1022'

The idea is to start a new ssh connection to the machine and use screen to get back to your disconnected session which should be still running.

**Steps**

1. `ssh user@machine -p 1022 # get back to the machine being upgraded`
2. `sudo screen -list        # this will list the screen sessions available`

You'll be looking for the line starting with `somenumber.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window`.

This session may be in Attached or Detached state, it doesn't matter.

3. `sudo screen -d -r root/somenumber.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window #command will get you back to your session and go on from the point where you left it pressing that fatal CTRL + C`

At some point during this, suggestions may appear on your console to press this or that key to resume or pause/unpause the upgrade process.

**Example**

```
user@machine:~# sudo screen -list
There is a screen on:
        1883.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window       (11/14/2022 09:45:15 AM)        (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.
user@machine:~# sudo screen -d -r root/1883.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window
```