# Access ubuntu terminal/sudo after pressing ctrl c and restaring while upgrading system

Tags: command-line, upgrade, kernel, 14.10, 15.04

I tried to upgrade my system from 14.10 to 15.04 and while I was installing it asked me if I want to replace config file. I tried to compare, then didn't know how to exit Ipressed ctrl c and then I tried to restart the computer but I get from ubuntu the message `end Kernel panic  - not syncing`. I thought using the solution right [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146308/hit-ctrlc-during-do-release-upgrade-did-i-break-it) but how can I use sudo now? How I open the terminal? Thanks

Comment: That's a bit urgent so I'll be glad to get an answer.