# I hit control-c in a do-release-upgrade subprocess. How do I recover?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, do-release-upgrade

In the process of upgrading from Utopic Unicorn to Vivid Vervet, `do-release-upgrade` asked me which version of a configuration file to keep. I chose the option to run a (root) shell, noticed there were only a few small changes, and ran `vim` to merge the two versions. I'm used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to finish inserts, but it seems that in this case that actually killed something, as I was returned to one of my own shells.

After a bit of investigation, I noticed that the `vim` instance was somehow still running. I killed it and was returned to the root shell I'd started it from. I then exited the root shell, expecting to be returned to the upgrade script, but instead, the `tmux` instance I ran it in exited.

At this point, I can see that the script is still running and presumably doing *something* (it seems to consistently have 11% CPU usage). Unlike some cases similar to mine, there is no `screen` or `byobu` instance to reattach to—in fact, according to `ps`, it's lost its controlling terminal.

What happened here, and what should I do return my system to a sane state and complete the upgrade?

Comment: This looks similar to yours: http://serverfault.com/q/387547/109361

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-paste from server fault:

> AFAICT, there was no way to reattach to the upgrade process. However,
>   it wasn't a disaster at all. I killed the hanging `dpkg` process, and
>   then ran `dpkg --configure -a`. This walks you through reconfiguring all
>   packages already installed on the system, tidying up any problems
>   whilst it does so. After that, I used `aptitude` to upgrade the
>   remaining packages, which had already been downloaded, but hadn't been
>   installed or configured.

Courtesy: https://serverfault.com/q/387547/109361

**Update:**

If `aptitude` is not installed in your system, then the same can be done using `apt-get`, as I understand.

This is what worked for the OP:

> The upgrade script had already changed the sources in
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list` from Utopic to Vivid and disabled all the
>   third-party sources. After `dpkg --configure --pending` and `apt-get install --fix-broken`, did `apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`,
>   and then rebooted, everything seems like it's working now.

**More Info:**

From the related [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1444502), doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` seems to be the key to get things working properly.

Comment: Only one problem, you can't install `aptitude` at this point.

Comment: @A.B, How can we know that its not installed already? Maybe its already installed, otherwise the same can be done using `apt-get`, as I understand.

Comment: Than you should write that in your answer to avoid confusions.

Comment: @BlacklightShining, `systemd` has replaced `upstart` in Ubuntu 15.04.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management

Comment: @BlacklightShining, This might help with the transition: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: @BlacklightShining, That's great. I have added more information to the answer, including what worked for you.