# Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 is taking too long

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I'm upgrading Ubuntu on a new laptop , 16.04 to 18.04, following instructions [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver).

The last command I ran was:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Now I'm stuck on

> To continue please press [ENTER]
>
> Inhibiting until Ctrl+C is pressed...

I can't say exactly, but I started upgrading about three hours ago. It seems to me that the upgrade is taking too long.
I also noticed that I have no network activity in System Monitor, and the Total Received number is less than the upgrade download size (which is 1 189 M).

Is this possible to check my upgrade status?
May the System Monitor received size not taking into account any traffic?

**UPDATE**

I canceled the process and I saw that there's actually an error.

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>
> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

So I looked for the process that was blocking it

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

It happened to be aptd. I checked its pid

```
ps -e | grep aptd
```

and killed it

```
sudo kill -9 14806
```

After that I was able to run (as @Jos suggested):

```
sudo apt install -f
```

And started the upgrade process from the beginning.

Comment: Your update process ought to give you a complete log of what is being downloaded, unpacked, installed and configured. If it doesn't, you can interrupt the upgrade and do `sudo apt install -f` to see where you were.

Comment: @Jos Sorry for asking twice :) Do I understand correctly that the log is supposed to display in the terminal ? Because I there's no download messages, at least not in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, straight after the `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: See here as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/146308/hit-ctrlc-during-do-release-upgrade-did-i-break-it

Comment: @Jos Thanks for the link, although I've read it already.  :) I've managed to upgrade successfully. Your comment helped, so if you care to add it as an answer, I will accept it, for the completeness' sake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update process ought to give you a complete log of what is being downloaded, unpacked, installed and configured. If it doesn't, there is something wrong, but at this point we can only speculate what. However, you can simply interrupt the upgrade with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Then do `sudo apt install -f` to see where you were.

One thing may have gone wrong though. If the upgrade process *was* running, then early on your Ubuntu version string was changed (in your case from `xenial` to `bionic`) in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You may need to change that back before retrying the upgrade.

Answer (score 47):

I got the same message. Pressing Enter got it going. Not sure what the message means, but pressing Enter did the upgrade from there.

Comment: Same problem caused me all kinds of annoyances: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031881/dist-upgrade-seems-to-have-created-an-issue/1064512#1064512

Comment: Glad I found this answer!
Was waiting for something to happen when upgrading to 18.10 and after pressing Enter the upgrade really started.

Comment: Same here.  I must have waited 20m for something to happen.  To be clear, you  need to hit enter twice. The first time you're prompted and hitting enter brings up the message "Inhibiting until Ctrl+C is pressed..."  The second time is not prompted, but you still need to hit enter. Once you do you'll see the upgrade messages indicating package downloading, selecting, unpacking, etc.

Comment: This is a problem from bionic to focal as well... weird interface

Comment: Same to Groovy Gorilla.   Very confusing message :(

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same. How I fixed it:

1. `cp /etc/apt/source.list.distUpgrade`
2. `apt update`
3. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

It then should start installing again. Do not press Ctrl+C, but just hit [ENTER]