# Continue Ubuntu Upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: do-release-upgrade, 19.10

Ubuntu interrupted an upgrade due to a locally changed grub file. I selected the option to open a new terminal to see the differences. It just kicked me back to the existing terminal as root instead. I closed that terminal because I typed something that kicked me out of root. How do I get back to the upgrade process? dpkg is locked. I don't have the screen command. It's VERY similar to this: [Hit Ctrl+c during do-release-upgrade. Did I break it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146308/hit-ctrlc-during-do-release-upgrade-did-i-break-it). None of those solutions work.

Checking the version, I get back 19.10, so I cannot just try do-release-upgrade again.

Comment: I can't picture what you're describing, but in the newly opened terminal I would ^D to exit it and expect to get back to the upgrade process. Usually even if terminal gets killed (I was doing an upgrade last night & accidentally kicked the power cord out and of course upgrade died - I booted a 'live' to `fsck` the file-system, then booted & logged in (via term) and tried to continue upgrade (the continuation may be `sudo apt full-upgrade`) and when errors occurred just followed suggestions). My box is back to normal; I'd expect same for you...

Comment: That did not work. The terminal was killed by closing the tab.

Comment: You could try removing the lock by running `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` then attempt to continue the upgrade by running `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I get an error from dpkg stating "error processing package apparmor (--configure): installed apparmor package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1". Attempting to reinstall apparmor fails with "No file name for apparmor:amd64"

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 19.04 problems install upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501)

Comment: Thanks, though that wasn't effective. I think the only option at this point is the nuclear one. At least this gives me the opportunity to try another distro if 19.10 and gnome 3.34 don't fix the substantial usability problems of the previous versions.